# Can Promise.race be used for catching e.g. an error event while waiting for a Promise to resolve/reject?

Tags: javascript, events, promise, async-await

I have a multiplayer card game where a client plays a round.
The function to play this round let's say `playRound` returns a `Promise` if the round was successfully played or something went wrong for example the client tried to cheat.

What I want to do now is to catch an event from an `EventEmitter` if the client errors or leaves unexpectedly. Because it would be nice to reuse the catch handler of the rejected play round promise I thought of promisifying the event and then just do a `Promise.race()` with the `playRound` function so only if the event occurs and if the `Promise` is still pending it should reject.

My code which is highly simplified and should just help to understand the problem looks like this:

```
// function only rejects if on error handler gets called and it never resolves
// underscore param should indicate that the resolve function is never used
const onClientError = client => new Promise((_, reject) => {
  const handler = () => {
    reject(Error(`client encountered an error`));
  };

 client.api.onError(handler);
});

try {
  const round = await Promise.race([
    playRound(client),
    onClientError(client),
  ]);

  // check for unexpected behaviour
  if (!round) {
    throw Error('played round is undefined');
  }

  // return the result
  return round;
} catch (error) {
  // do something if rejected or on client error
}
```

In my opinion it should be no problem to use it like that but I have a feeling that there is a better way to solve this. But the state should always be valid because `round` either throws or is defined.

My question is now, is it bad practice to do something like this(a promise that never resolves in combination with a promise race) or do you know of a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You forgot to call the `onClientError` function, but otherwise using `Promise.race` is totally fine.

Comment: You are totally right. Must have missed it while copying from my code. Thanks.